# TypeError: an integer is required while running a for loop with items

Tags: python

I am facing TypeError: an integer is required. But could not figure exactly where the problem is. I can't post the code as it is company policy, but i will provide a reference snippet code.

Note : This logic is run in testcase with UnitTest as base class under api runTest

Python Used 2.7.6

```
files = funct1() # This returns a list of files created using NamedTemporaryFile 
# with delete passed as False The files are json format the returned 
# data is a list with filenames. Then I perform the below loop. 

for item in files: #Type Error posted for this line
    func2(item)
```

Strange is : For one example I Know it returns two files in the list, So i manually send the files calling func2 as below after getting the list.  No Type Errors are seen. 
So cant exactly blame the func2 also.

```
func2(files[0])
func2(files[1])
```

and there was no error. This indicates the list contains file names properly.

Also printed the filenames before  to check, the names are printed properly.
Even tried having a loop below

```
length = len(files)
for idx in range(length): << same Type Error again
    fun2(files[idx])
```

If the same functionality is done through loop, the error comes up.
If I just print the names before this it prints fine.

Func2: It performs reading the file and executes action based on the file data.

If some one can help where to look. Is it in func2 as it takes only one parameter and performs find the file in a given set of paths, then open and json load and other actions.

Comment: Please show the error with the full traceback.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the `for`? (the stack trace would show that line as its last error item). The only way the second example could error like that is if `files` is an object that implements its own `__len__` method and that method has a bug.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
For instance, assign a list of file names to `files` and continue from there, in one or two examples that let us see the error.

Comment: `files = funct1()` has problems. Please check it.